# The ngChange expression is evaluated when array/object used in ngOptions is set to empty/undefined/null

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, ng-options, angularjs-ng-change

I've just discovered a strange feature/bug in Angular.js.

Lets assume we have a selectbox, where options are filled by ngOptions directive. We set a change listener on the selectbox using ngChange directive.

```
<select ng-model="model" ng-options="item for item in list" ng-change="foo()"></select>
```

We define scope as follows:

```
$scope.list = [1,2,3,4,5];
$scope.model = 3;

$scope.foo = function() {
    console.log("change");
};
```

Then we somewhere in the code reset the array like this:

```
$scope.list = [];
```

If we look at the console, we can see that function `foo()` was called and text `"change"` was logged. However user didn't touch the selectbox and didn't change the selected value. According to the documentation

> The ngChange expression is only evaluated when a change in the input
>   value causes a new value to be committed to the model.
>
> It will **not be evaluated**:
>
> - if the value returned from the $parsers transformation pipeline has not changed
> - if the input has continued to be invalid since the model will stay null
> - if the **model is changed programmatically and not by a change to the input value**

The input value was **not** changed. The model was **not** changed. Only the array (with an object it's the same behavior) used to generate options was changed **programmatically**.

By inspecting the `select` element I also discovered that `ng-dirty` class was set to the element, even though user never touched the selectbox (class `ng-untouched` is still set).

Why is this happening? It is a strange feature I can't understand or it is a bug? Am I doing something wrong? Do you know a solution for this problem?

Comment: The input value **is** changed as soon as you modify the array that is being used to generate the options.

Comment: That's not true. I can modify the array anyway I want (add/remove elements, replace the whole array) and the model will not change, the ngChange expression will be not evaluated. And this is the expected behavior. Only empty/undefined/null array/object causes unexpected behavior.

Comment: You have `$scope.model = 3;`. In your view put `{{model}}` and observe the change when you call whatever code sets `$scope.list = []`.

Comment: In the meantime I also discovered the `model` is set to `null` when the `list` no longer contains the selected value. But your comment says someting different. It matters **how** you modify the array. But this is still a strange and unexpected behavior. When you assign to the model a value which is not on the list, there is no problem. You can do it and an empty option with the new value will be added to the selectbox. So why the model should be set to `null` when you do it in opposite order?

Comment: And what is the most important: in this case the model was changed by angular (triggered by a programmatic change) not by the user. So there is no logical reason to evaluate the ngChange expression, which was set for the case when user changes the input by clicking. Maybe I should visit the angular's github page to discuss this "feature". What do you think?

Comment: Angular isn't changing the model, the input (`<select>`) is changing the model because the value that was assigned to it is no longer a viable option since you have removed it. This is how `<select>` elements work. In the case where you specifically set the model value to something that is not currently an option on the `<select>` Angular is helping you out by automatically adding the option for you. You can certainly raise this as an issue on github, but I have a feeling you're not going to elicit a change - it's basic HTML behavior.

Comment: I need to correct myself. The new value wil not be set for the empty option. But that is not important now.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the list:

```
$scope.list = [];
```

This triggers the ng-change because it changes the options list, which changes the input value.

I see that you highlighted: **if the model is changed programmatically and not by a change to the input value**.

You are not changing the model programmatically in this case.

Comment: That's true, I am not changing the model programmaticalliy in this case. Angular is changing the model. What is very important. See my comment on my question.